angular Router reuse strategy custom class - inject service
I need to track components that are currently have been detached. I am thinking to use a service for that. I am trying to inject that service into the custom strategy class but, since it does not have a constructor, I don't see a way of doing it. Any idea?

You should be able to add a constructor as long as you call super() (like any other extends class). Otherwise the inject() function should also work (if you're in Angular 17 or newer) and avoids a child constructor.
With a service like so:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DetachedComponentTrackingService { }

The strategy would look similar to:
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  RouteReuseStrategy 
} from '@angular/router';
import { 
  DetachedComponentTrackingService 
} from './.../detached-component-tracking.service';

export class DetachedAwareRouteReuseStrategy 
  extends RouteReuseStrategy {

  private readonly functionInjectedService =
    inject(DetachedComponentTrackingService);

  constructor(
    private readonly constructorInjectedService: DetachedComponentTrackingService
  ) { 
    // RouteReuseStrategy
    super();
  }

  override shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    // this.functionInjectedService...
    // this.constructorInjectedService...
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

  // Other overrides...
}

Then just provide the strategy like any other provider token:
import { AppComponent } from './.../app.component';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { 
  DetachedComponentTrackingService 
} from './.../detached-component-tracking.service';
import { 
  DetachedAwareRouteReuseStrategy 
} from './.../detached-aware-route-reuse-strategy';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: DetachedAwareRouteReuseStrategy,
    },
    provideRouter([
      // Routes...
    ]),
  ],
});

There's a section of the providers documentation that covers useClass with dependencies and I'm not seeing any special considerations there.

Actually, I'm thinking you could avoid the super() call entirely if you use implements instead...

Line with super(); shows this error: 'super' can only be referenced in a derived class

With constructor, but without super() call it compiles, but pages are not loading. Not sure, what you mean by implements.

No, I was wrong, it's not compiling. This is the error message: Error: projects/......./app.module.ts:83:23 - error NG2005: The class 'AWARouteReuseStrategy' cannot be created via dependency injection, as it does not have an Angular decorator. This will result in an error

Which version of Angular are you using?

And could you please edit an MRE into your question? Or a StackBlitz or similar?

I am using version  17.

I do have an example, but it works fine. I am getting both constructor and inject versions compiling fine. But when I run it I am getting this error: main.ts:18 Could not load file 'assets/config/config.dev.json': {"name":"NullInjectorError","ngTempTokenPath":["InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS","[object Object]","Router","RouteReuseStrategy","DetachedComponentTrackingService","DetachedComponentTrackingService"]} and pages are not loading.

That error says that the config.dev.json file couldn't be loaded because providers for HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, an unknown object, Router, RouteReuseStrategy, DetachedComponentTrackingService, and DetachedComponentTrackingService are missing.  Make sure that your dependencies are provided at the correct levels. You might get the most help by asking a new question and including your hierarchy and what's provided at each level.
